# How is cppcoro::task asynchronous?

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine, cppcoro

From the [cppcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#taskt) docs:

> A task represents an **asynchronous** computation that is executed lazily in that the execution of the coroutine **does not start until the task is awaited**.

(My emphasis)

The example from the docs:

```cpp
#include <cppcoro/read_only_file.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/task.hpp>

cppcoro::task<int> count_lines(std::string path)
{
  auto file = co_await cppcoro::read_only_file::open(path);

  int lineCount = 0;

  char buffer[1024];
  size_t bytesRead;
  std::uint64_t offset = 0;
  do
  {
    bytesRead = co_await file.read(offset, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    lineCount += std::count(buffer, buffer + bytesRead, '\n');
    offset += bytesRead;
  } while (bytesRead > 0);

  co_return lineCount;
}

cppcoro::task<> usage_example()
{
  // Calling function creates a new task but doesn't start
  // executing the coroutine yet.
  cppcoro::task<int> countTask = count_lines("foo.txt");

  // ...

  // Coroutine is only started when we later co_await the task.
  int lineCount = co_await countTask;

  std::cout << "line count = " << lineCount << std::endl;
}
```

If the execution does not start until the task is awaited, how is this not equivalent to ordinary blocking IO?

If you actually want to have the IO functions run asynchronously and concurrently, how do you write the code?

Comment: How?  You use threads.  Co-routines SIMULATE asyncronous operation, but they are cooperatively shareng one thread.

Answer (score 0):

The coroutine doesn't need to run in the same thread that created the coroutine, as seen in [the thread example in the documentation of coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines). coroutines are a low level building block for asynchronous systems, that still require an executor to start and resume work efficiently (for example when a non-blocking socket is ready for write), so it is meant for use in library code ([Asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/)), not in product code.

The tasks might easily be created in one thread then offloaded to multiple other threads for execution, or they can be started and paused and completed in any order or any thread depending on the resources availability, hence the "async" part.

if you want a simple way to introduce an async task that runs in the backgroud you should use [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), which excutes work in another thread concurrently, and is designed for use in product code.

---

another type of asynchronous tasks are generators which are executing asynchronously but not concurrently as seen in the `cppcoro` documentation.

```
cppcoro::generator<const std::uint64_t> fibonacci()
{
  std::uint64_t a = 0, b = 1;
  while (true)
  {
    co_yield b;
    auto tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b += tmp;
  }
}

void usage()
{
  for (auto i : fibonacci())
  {
    if (i > 1'000'000) break;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Both functions are being executed, and the stack pointer is continously shifting from one function to the other.